# How to fill new custom field on already existing accounts?

Tags: apex, batch, account

I need experts advice on the situation we have.

We are creating a new datawarehouse and copy all the already existing accounts from salesforce to our new datawarehouse. The other systems in the company query the new DW instead of salesforce for any information.

For this, we are creating a new custom field on the account object and fill this field with the custom ID because we don't want to use the salesforce generated ID and this new field will be common across all the systems.

So the question is, If I create a new custom field on the Account object, How do I update this field on the already existing 10000 Accounts in the salesforce?

I know that I need to use the batch apex to update this field for all the existing accounts when everybody is in bed.

Just wanted to know if any body has any suggestions on this approach or any examples to help me with this?

If any body has any algorithm or strategy to create this new field with the ID that would be great.

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have freedom over the format of this custom ID field then you can add a normal Salesforce auto-number field. Unique values will be automatically inserted when records are inserted in the future and if you check:

> Generate Auto Numbers for existing records

when you add the field, the numbering of existing records will be done for you (though it will take a while).

**PS** Why not make the Salesforce ID the common ID especially if all the data originates in Salesforce? Then there is no need to generate a different ID or to have to relate the IDs to each other.

Comment: My DBA is against using the salesforce generated ID and he wants to use the ID which we generate. He says that salesforce can change the ID in the future.

Comment: @javanoob To an external database a Salesforce ID is just a text string - unclear what his concern about that changing would be. If he means he is concerned about an ID value changing for an existing object then it won't. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Keith, The response I received from my DBA when I told him that we can use salesforce ID is "You are too young", so I am just following his orders :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the dataloader and Excel. I'm assuming you've created a custom field with the 'External ID' option checked on the account object.

1. Export Salesforce Id's of the accounts using the dataloader.
2. Export the datawarehouse account data.
3. Do an Excel vlookup to match the account data.
4. Save the file in csv format then do an update using the dataloader.

Comment: The dataware is not yet setup and it does not have any data. salesforce needs to feed data to datawarehouse.